# Can I find a job on Stack Overflow as a self-taught programmer with no professional experience?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I'm currently looking for a remote job, and I thought that Stack Overflow might be a good place to find it. However, I'm completely self-taught and have no professional experience yet, but the Developer Story requires me to "add a complete current position or education item", and until I do that, my matches are on hold. Does that mean that employers won't contact me?

I don't think that it's impossible to be a good programmer without formal education or work experience, and I'm a good example of this. I have a lot of reputation (I'm in the top 3000 users) and my answers have helped at least tens of thousands of programmers. I also have a GitHub repository with almost a hundred stars. Is this not enough? Joel Spolsky [said that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20491/211784):

> if you're in the top, say, 5000 Stack Overflow users [...] I would be **extremely** surprised if you aren't in high demand and earning in the top 10 percentile.

I'm not even looking for a job with a very high compensation; any job would be fine. Do I stand a chance of finding it here, or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: Well, you may not have had _formal_ education, but I'd try to describe your education anyway. Perhaps add an online course, or something else. And then, of course, you can see from there. Your job chances are dependent on a lot of factors, but education and work experience are important ones.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth When I try to add an education item, it requires a university or institution name, so I don't suppose I can enter "Stack Overflow" or "MDN" there.

Comment: I don't see why not. The system isn't really intended for it, but you'll have to work around it.

Comment: I mean, won't you just find out if you try? you could always add self-employed in the story. also can you add online certifications? do a 10 day free course on edx/any other site maybe

Comment: Did you go to high school, elementary school, or even kindergarten? That is your most recent education, which you would use when you are looking for jobs outside Stack Overflow. Developer Story allows you to write any school name, it doesn't have to be already in the system.

Comment: A programmer without Professional background or Education is not something unusual. Back in the day, it was not uncommon to have programmer with "only" an electrical / electronic background.
Many programmer don't have a conputer science degree. (I remerber an old stat about 50%-50%).

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri I did finish high school, and I even had some programming classes there. I put that as an education item in my Developer Story.

Comment: I just raised your use case to the talent / jobs product team,  and it does look like you hit an unforeseen edge case. They're working on a response now. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: 34,000+ Reputation without formal education and work experience. Just woww!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi No, he has answered 745 questions, not 87 questions. You were looking at MSO answer count

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi: I have a formal education and years of experience, and I do declare I am not insulted by this question at all `:=)`.

Comment: @DragandDrop yeah that's nice and all, but that's from the times there hardly _was_ any formal CS education. Nowadays there's one at almost every education level. I think the OP is in for a tough one, wanting to do remote work only without any education or work experience. Sure, there's a shortage of developers in about every field, but good luck finding an employer wanting to take _that_ risk.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That "your matches are on hold" means that employers won't be able to find you when looking for developers, but you can still apply for positions you are interested in.

If you would like to be discoverable by employers, you could add an education entry. As [you mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369343/can-i-find-a-job-on-stack-overflow-as-a-self-taught-programmer-with-no-professio#comment599410_369343) you could add "Stack Overflow" or "MDN" as the institution and, on "Summary or achievements" clarify that you're self taught and that this is a resource you use to learn.

That would get your profile complete enough to be displayed to employers.

Comment: what does MDN mean?

Comment: that's probably a question for Michał, but I guess they referred to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Answer (score 38):

Given your Stack Overflow and GitHub scores, I'd say you were probably very employable, but there are a lot of factors at play, including your location. The number of jobs available at Stack Overflow Jobs is small compared to the number of roles in the market.

I wouldn't worry about employers seeking a match and contacting you – just look at roles on SOJ you think would be suitable, and contact them proactively.

I would also advise not to get too hung up on using SOJ – use whatever works. There are hundreds of job boards out there, and recently when I did some job hunting, I bookmarked the top 10-15 of them (suitable for my country and skills) and did a search on each one every day.

One thing that can be helpful to employers is to have something to demonstrate in interviews. If it is on the web, you can demonstrate that both in telephone interviews and in face-to-face interviews. A web app is excellent, but even a systems diagram can be enormously useful.

The last round of interviews I did were successful because I showed a client something I had built for myself. It was a micro-service based application, with tests for most repos, and CI. It demonstrated the use of a lot of technologies they were already using, and they remarked on the coincidence of their commercial project having a similar internal architecture.

### Using the employment history fields

The validation on the employer and prior employer fields is fairly light, so put in here what you were doing for each phase of your career. I have used my SOJ Developer Story as a "pre-CV" in the past - *none* of my prior employers have a real name here. I use "Financial Company", "Start-up", etc (so that I can control who contacts my past employers for references - they can only do so once I have sent them a PDF CV via email).

### Update for remote jobs

Since you are looking for remote work, and given your circumstances, that may be somewhat harder. SOJ offers a good number of remote roles, so it is not the availability of remote that is the potential sticking point. The issue I think you will bump into is that new software engineers are generally thought to be best "incubated" in an office-based team before they are allowed to strike out on their own.

Your case is unusual though since you seem to be an accomplished programmer, and it is just the commercial experience that you lack. You may there just need to think about how you can demonstrate an ability to:

- work solo and generally unsupervised
- communicate with team members remotely
- manage your own time

### Be persistent

When looking for a job, **you do have to be persistent.** Even experienced engineers struggle with rude, pushy, forgetful and otherwise shoddy recruitment agents. My approach is that I set up a Trello board in a Kanban style, with column headings like:

- Apply next
- Waiting
- Dead

I use reminders to judge when each waiting thing needs a telephone call chase, and I am perfectly happy to ring someone every day until it's clear it is no longer worth persisting with.

The *Apply next* column would be fuelled with new potential roles frequently, found using SOJ and other job boards. Keep all your job boards bookmarked (ideally with a ready-made search) so they are easy to go through.

Comment: Regarding my location, I'm looking for a fully remote job.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski I don't think "matches" means a company will contact you. It just means that they found a job for you according to your skills "You've been matched!
We've found a few job opportunities for you.
Recommendations are based on your experience, interests, and preferences."

Answer (score 13):

#### Disclaimer: Personal <strike>sermon</strike> rant follows:

It's also worth mentioning that Joel [also said](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20491/211784):

> Then keep going deeper and deeper. Scroll to page 5. Edit the URL and go right to page 100 where they have reputations in the 3000 range. Look at everyone. With the very rare exception of someone who got a lot of points for a silly answer, these are all obvious superstar programmers... the kind that most teams would kill for.

I'm going to restate it with emphasis of my own:

> Then **keep going** deeper and deeper. Scroll to page 5. Edit the URL and go right to page 100 where they have reputations in the 3000 range. **Look at everyone**. With the very rare exception of someone who got a lot of points for a silly answer, these are all obvious superstar programmers... the kind that most teams would kill for.

I'm going to toss out a wild idea, *there are some pretty damn good programmers out there with 1 rep on Stack Overflow, or possibly not even on the site*. I'm also going to float the idea that not every great programmer has time to maintain a presence on Github, LinkedIn, or other places.

So whether you have no experience to show yet, or maybe you just don't like using Stack Overflow Q&A, or maybe you work *purely* to fund your ultimate passion for something else that isn't likely to ever make money - companies are finally starting to wake up to the fact that the traditional HR mentality has been holding them back for years.

***Apply, showing aptitude*** and a company worth their salt is going to notice you. You've got the benefit of lots of rep and some good activity on GH, but even if you didn't, my advice would be to apply *in a way that shows you've read up on the company, understand their problems and goals, and have something you can't wait to contribute*. Don't feel like you need to make excuses for not having a CS degree any more than someone else shouldn't feel like they need to make excuses for having lots of magic Internet points - ***that you feel passionately that you want the job because you can do it*** is what matters most.

Remember, the goal in applying is introduction to get yourself into an interview where you can show them that you can add value to their team. So if you ..  show them that you can add value to their team  .. that should be it.

When this whole thing took off (as in rebuilding from the first dot-com boom) we (as in the industry, collectively) really didn't have any idea of what a good programmer looked like, acted like, studied - all kinds of people just discovered that they had strange talents for specialization in things that they didn't know existed even a few years previously.

Then we screwed up and 'type cast' what a typical developer should look like, act like, have studied, have worked at, should be doing in their spare time and .. we should have followed the KISS model way back when and we'd be in a much better place. Good programmers are the people that are lucky enough to realize that they're good at solving strange, abstract but *rampant* problems. And sometimes they realize that pretty late in life.

That's not to say that your participation on the site is *not* going to help you, it definitely will, and we're grateful to have you helping others. But, every time you knock on a door and say *I'm unconventional, I don't fit in your mold, but here's my take on your problems and how I can help fix them* - you make this industry a little better than it was. You reinforce that a knock on the back door is just as valuable as an 'influx funnel' from a recruiting agency.

No degree? No previous experience? Hogwash - you've got plenty the minute you know deep down you can do something. Everything else is just a different means of showing that.

Products like Talent / Jobs *have* to cater to the way people are currently doing things *while gently nudging the industry in better directions*. And your case is one that (I personally) think we could be better handling, which is why I made sure the product team saw it.

But don't underestimate yourself, or you just make sure others make the same mistake of underestimating you. Just get out there and apply, and if you must,  tell 'em I told you so.

Comment: Ooh, everyone reading this can say "hey I got a personal recommendation from Tim Post at Stack Overflow". Hope you're ready for a bunch of calls from recruiters chasing up some references requests `:-)`

Comment: @halfer If recruiters start calling me to confirm this instead of asking if I'm still a Flash developer, _mission accomplished_. (I was never a flash developer)

Comment: Recruiter calls up candidate: "ah, so you're a Flash developer?" Candidate: "how dare you!" `(puts phone down)`

Comment: You have no idea how this answer is extremely encouraging.

Answer (score 5):

My situation is very similar to yours. I never had formal CS education. I haven't been contacted through Stack Overflow. Yet I've applied to 6-7 different jobs on Stack Overflow and I got an interview with 3 very good companies. None of them led to a hiring.

I never got the chance to ask them whether or not they looked at my Stack Overflow profile or not. Most of them had their own internal application pages.

What I learned from the experience of talking with the recruiters was that all of them liked it when I said I found their job posting from Stack Overflow, it kinda gives them a nerdy vibe. Yet none of them asked me anything that came out from my developer story. I honestly don't believe any of them looked at my developer story. They just wanted to follow their **own** interview process and didn't want to get out of their comfort zone.

From my understanding recruiters don't really know how to use developer story *yet*. Still having a nice developer story will be rewarding in the long run. It increases your networking chances. So definitely go for it. Add your GitHub profile, lectures, good answers, books you've read to it.

Tip: One of the best Developer stories I've seen belongs to [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/97337). Give it a look.

Comment: Most recruiters (i.e. not the folks doing the hiring, but intermediaries) know very little about technology, and are only a filter to stop completely unsuitable folks from contacting their client. To some degree, recruiters are _intended_ to get in the way, and your job is to "play the game" with them long enough to get your foot in the door. Be very keen to speak to the client, and if a recruiter is in doubt you can suggest a telephone interview, which is less time and bother for the client.

Comment: Once you get an interview, hopefully you can talk to or meet people who are actually technical, and at that point I'd argue a developer story does not matter so much as the stuff you can present to them. If you do not have a CS education, it matters not: (1) be passionate about your craft, (2) show them you enjoy it - hobby out of control etc. and (3) create stuff that works. Practical and useful outcomes are way more useful than academic/training certificates.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your reputation I thought you would be already working as a developer or must have a great experience as a developer.

There is a huge chance of getting you employed looking at your reputation. In my experience small companies they will mostly look at your background your education, your experience. Since you have no formal education or any experience the chances over there are very low. But here's the thing: giant companies like Google, Facebook or Apple they even accept single page resume. You can add "self employed" and provide your education you have, and give your Stack Overflow profile reference in your resume. Or even if you apply to the SO I am sure they will consider your application looking at your reputation.

Don't depend on SO only there are lot of platforms where you can apply for jobs. Look around find out all the job posting platforms and keep applying. Just keep trying. I am sure you will get one very easily.

### Edit

As per your question you can add your current position as "self employed" and add your education you have completed yet. You can go for few online good courses you like, I know you will already nail them. Get certificate and add it in your profile. This will definitely be an add to your profile or to your resume.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, the main bulk of the Q was that OP cant properly make use of SOJ because he cant fill out certain details

Comment: @WhatsThePoint it's a discussion - in an answer you'll not always see an actual answer - you might see other points of view as well = that is how meta works